# Centering div in a document

Tags: html, css, centering

I know this question has been asked many times before, but none of the answers have worked for me. I am coding in HTML5 and CSS 3.0. I am trying to center a div tag in a page, which contains three thumbnails that link to other pictures. I want the pictures to sit next to each other, with a margin of 0 (so they'll touch each other). Here is the html code I have:

```
<div id="main">
    <h1>hello</h1>
    <div id="gallery">
        <a class="trigger" href="images/fulls/01.jpg">
            <img class="thumb" src="images/thumbs/01.jpg">
        </a>
        <a class="trigger" href="images/fulls/02.jpg">
            <img class="thumb" src="images/thumbs/02.jpg">
        </a>
        <a class="trigger" href="images/fulls/03.jpg">
            <img class="thumb" src="images/thumbs/03.jpg">
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
body {
    font-family: arial;
    background: darkgray;
    color:white;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 3px black;
    text-align: center;
}
#gallery {
    text-align: center;
    width: 462px;
}
.trigger {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
```

This results in the title "hello" being centered, and the three thumbnails stuck to the very left. They have no distance between them, and aligned in a row as I expected, but I cannot get them to center.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove `float:left` from your images and use `display: inline-block;` then add `margin: 0 auto;` to your `#gallery`

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Dc5Af/**

Comment: I removed `float:left;` on the images and added `display: inline-block;` on the gallery. The images are now centered, but I cannot get the images to touch each other. Even when I set `margin:0;`.

Comment: Yes you should try `padding:0;` and you might need to do `margin-left: -2px;` because i know `display: inline-block;` does have a little gap bug, you could try removing all whitespace in your html images.

Comment: That's because it isn't a margin, but a whitespace character (space, tab, new line) between the `img` tag and the `a` tag.

Answer (score 3):

Use `margin: 0 auto` to automatically distribute the margins on the left and right of the block-level element:

```
#gallery {
    text-align: center;
    width: 462px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Of course it can be `margin: <length> auto` if you wish to have a margin on the top/bottom as well, just ensure that `margin-left` and `margin-right` are set to `auto`.

This will center the `div` in its parent (whether that be `body` or something else), but you are floating your anchors left. Floating automatically makes the elements *block-level*, so `text-align` will not apply to them (rather their children, if any, will inherit the property).

Remove the display and float properties of the `.trigger` class:

```
.trigger {
    position: relative;
}
```

I'm not sure if you need relative positioning for something else or why it's there, but I've left it there for now in case you do need it for something else.

If the images are not touching, it is because there is a space somewhere before or after the `img` element. Ensure that the `img` tag is between the `a` tags with no space before or after, nor any tabs or newlines. More about this problem: [Fighting the Space Between Inline Block Elements](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)

See [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qeFyw/1/).

Comment: It didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

This should work
    #gallery{
      width: 462px;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }

Comment: @sodiumnitrate then try:
`#gallery a img{margin-left: 50%;}`

Answer (score 0):

i am thinking that you should try something like

```
#gallery {
    text-align: center;
    width: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```